# Binding WPF DataGrid to List<Interface>

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello I have a DataGrid and I have different reports that I want to show. I'm going to change the classes so they are shorter in here but Idea is the same.

Lets say that I Have an Interface called IReports

```
public interface IReports
{
}
```

and three classes called Students, Classes, Cars

```
public class Students:IReports
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}  

public class Classes : IReports
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

}   
public class Cars : IReports
{
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

The List

```
private List<IReports> _reportsTable;    

public List<IReports> ReportsTable
    {
        get { return _reportsTable; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_reportsTable), value); }
    }
```

the DataGrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsList}"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="0"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          Grid.RowSpan="6"/>
```

Okay, so what is important here is they all have different property names and some have more some have less. How can I bind the DataGrid to look at the different properties? This is MVVM if that makes any difference.

Update: What this will always only use one of the classes at a time.but when someone changes a combobox it will fire an event that will fill the `IList<IReports>`.

[image]

Comment: Since the list is of type IReports, call you can bind to are properties provided by that interface

Comment: Okay, so what do you do in this situation?

Comment: do you want one DataGrid that supports all 3 datatypes? Are all columns going to be visible at all times?

Comment: yes, I would like to support all three types

Comment: all column in that datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What this will **always only use one of the classes at a time**. but when someone changes a combobox it will fire an event that will fill the IList<IReports>.

The way I understand the above is that you never mix different elements inside the list (i.e. it contains **only**  `Classes`, `Students` or  `Cars`). All the other answers are assuming the list contains mixed content, but if that's the true, then `DataGrid` is simply not the right presenter for such content.

If the above assumption is correct, then the only problem is how to represent different lists with a single bindable property. As can be seen in [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx), when dealing with collection, data binding does not really care if they are generic or not. The recognizable source types are the non generic `IEnumerable`, `IList` and `IBindingList`. However, the collection view implementation is using some rules to determine the **element type** of the collection, by seeking for generic type argument of implemented `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces by the actual data source class, by checking the first available item, or taking the information from [ITypedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation etc. All the rules and their precedence can be seen in the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionView.cs,6bba3d146e043790).

With all that in mind, one possible solution could be to change the `ReportsTable` property type to allow assigning `List<Classes>` or `List<Students` or `List<Cars>`. Any common class/interface will work (remember, data binding will check the actual type returned by `GetType()`) like `object`, `IEnumerable`, `IList`, `IEnumerable<IReports>` etc., so I'll choose the closest covariant type to `List<IReports` which is `IReadOnlyList<IReports>`:

```
private IReadOnlyList<IReports> _reportsTable;

public IReadOnlyList<IReports> ReportsTable
{
    get { return _reportsTable; }
    set { SetProperty(ref (_reportsTable), value); }
}
```

Now when you do this

```
viewModel.ReportsTable = new List<Students>
{
    new Students { Name = "A" },
    new Students { Name = "B" },
    new Students { Name = "C" },
    new Students { Name = "D" },
};
```

you get

[image]

while with this

```
viewModel.ReportsTable = new List<Classes>
{
    new Classes { ClassName = "A", StudentName = "A" },
    new Classes { ClassName = "A", StudentName ="B" },
    new Classes { ClassName = "B", StudentName = "C" },
    new Classes { ClassName = "B", StudentName = "D" },
};
```

it shows

[image]

and finally this

```
viewModel.ReportsTable = new List<Cars>
{
    new Cars { Mileage = 100, CarType = "BMW", StudentName = "A" },
    new Cars { Mileage = 200, CarType = "BMW", StudentName = "B" },
    new Cars { Mileage = 300, CarType = "BMW", StudentName = "C" },
    new Cars { Mileage = 400, CarType = "BMW", StudentName = "D" },
};
```

results in

[image]

**UPDATE:** The above requires modifying the model to return concrete `List<T>` instances. If you want to keep the model as it is (i.e. returning `List<IReports>`), then you'll need a different solution, this time utilizing the `ITypedList`. In order to do that, we'll create a simple list wrapper using the [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx) base class:

```
public class ReportsList : Collection<IReports>, ITypedList
{
    public ReportsList(IList<IReports> source) : base(source) { }
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Count > 0 ? this[0].GetType() : typeof(IReports));
    }
    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return null; }
}
```

then change the bindable property to

```
private IList<IReports> _reportsTable;
public IList<IReports> ReportsTable
{
    get { return _reportsTable; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _reportsTable, value as ReportsList ?? new ReportsList(value)); }
}
```

and you are done.

Comment: Thank you as you have had the best answer yet, I do have a small problem when I add data I still cannot view data. I have read your great description multiple times but still cannot figure out where I'm going wrong. I have changed to IReadOnlyList<T>  but still cannot get it to show data. What else am I missing?

Comment: Can you give me an example? Are you adding data after attaching the list?

Comment: Other than that, changing the type of the bindable property to `IReadOnlyList<IReports>` is just one of the parts of the solution . The other very important part is to create and assign the instances of `List<T>` where the `T` is the **concrete** type.

Comment: I am actually getting data from EntityFramwork 6 .ToList()

Comment: The question is though if you work with interface, i.e. `List<IReports`> which I suspect, because otherwise you will not be able to assign it to the `List<IReports>` as in your original code (`List<T>` class is not covariant). Please check the actual type in the debugger, if it's a `List<IReports>`, let me know, we'll need to do something else.

Comment: I have added a picture, It is a List<IReports>

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes, I have a solution for such case too, will update the answer.

Comment: @JamTay317 Answer updated. Hopefully it should handle the case.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want a datagrid to show the various columns of various classes that implement an interface. If you hook the DataGrid's LoadingRow event, you can see what types of objects you are dealing with at runtime. You can use reflection to get the properties off the row's datacontext and then check the datagrid to see if there is a column for that property. If not, add it.

An issue will be if there are different types in the list and a type doesn't have a property that is in another type (like Cars doesn't have a Name property and both Students and Cars are in the list). If you edit a column for a property that doesn't exist on the object, you'll throw an exception. To get around this, you'll need a converter and style that applies it to the datagridcells. For fun, I also added a datatrigger that changes the background of the cell to Silver if it is disabled. One issue will be if you need to change the cell's style then you have to do it in the code (or change the style in the code to be based on your style).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" />
```

CS

```
private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = sender as DataGrid;
    var pis = e.Row.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var pi in pis)
    {
        // Check if this property already has a column in the datagrid
        string name = pi.Name;
        var q = dg.Columns.Where(_ => _.SortMemberPath == name);
        if (!q.Any())
        {
            // No column matches, so add one
            DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
            c.Header = name;
            c.SortMemberPath = name;
            System.Windows.Data.Binding b = new Binding(name);
            c.Binding = b;

            // All columns don't apply to all items in the list
            // So, we need to disable the cells that aren't applicable
            // We'll use a converter on the IsEnabled property of the cell
            b = new Binding();
            b.Converter = new ReadOnlyConverter();
            b.ConverterParameter = name;

            // Can't apply it directly, so we have to make a style that applies it
            Style s = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.IsEnabledProperty, b));
            // Add a trigger to the style to color the background when disabled
            var dt = new DataTrigger() { Binding = b, Value = false };
            dt.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Silver));
            s.Triggers.Add(dt);
            c.CellStyle = s;

            // Add the column to the datagrid
            dg.Columns.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

CS for the converter:

```
public class ReadOnlyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var prop = value.GetType().GetProperty(parameter as string);
            if (prop != null)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And, just to be complete, this is what I used to setup the data for the screenshot:

```
public List<IReports> ReportsTable { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ReportsTable = new List<IReports>() {
        new Students() { Name = "Student 1" },
        new Students() { Name = "Student 2" },
        new Classes() { ClassName="CS 101", StudentName = "Student 3" },
        new Cars() { CarType = "Truck", Mileage=12345, StudentName = "Student 4" }
    };
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I like the Idea of this, but is there a way to do it in MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a converter option to display a given string value, why not add a getter to the base interface.  Then, each class just returns its own, almost like every object can override its "ToString()" method  Since you would create a list such as for display, or picking, the value would be read-only anyhow, Make it just a getter...

```
public interface IReports
{
    string ShowValue {get;}
}

public class Students:IReports
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShowValue { get { return Name; } }
}  

public class Classes : IReports
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string ShowValue { get { return ClassName + " - " + StudentName ; } }
}   
public class Cars : IReports
{
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string ShowValue { get { return CarType + "(" + Mileage + ") - " + StudentName; } }
}
```

Then in your view model manager...

```
public class YourMVVMClass
{
        public YourMVVMClass()
        {
           SelectedRptRow = null;
           ReportsTable = new List<IReports>() 
           {
               new Students() { Name = "Student 1" },
               new Students() { Name = "Student 2" },
               new Classes() { ClassName="CS 101", StudentName = "Student 3" },
               new Cars() { CarType = "Truck", Mileage=12345, StudentName = "Student 4" }
           };
        }


        // This get/set for binding your data grid to
        public List<IReports> ReportsTable { get; set; }
        // This for the Selected Row the data grid binds to
        public IReports SelectedRptRow { get; set; }

        // This for a user double-clicking to select an entry from
        private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Now, you can look directly at the SelectedRptRow
            // as in the data-grid binding declaration.
            if (SelectedRptRow is Classes)
                MessageBox.Show("User selected a class item");
            else if( SelectedRptRow is Cars)
                MessageBox.Show("User selected a car item");
            else if( SelectedRptRow is Students)
                MessageBox.Show("User selected a student item");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("No entry selected");
        }
}
```

Finally in your form/view

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsTable}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRptRow}" 
        MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="200" Height ="140" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Report Item" 
                Width="180"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                CanUserSort="False"
                Binding="{Binding Path=ShowValue}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image: Result binding and double-click from datagrid]

The other answers using the converters are just another path, but this avenue to me is easier as you can change each individual class and expand / adjust as needed.  The exposed "ShowValue" getter is common to all instances of the "IReports", so the binding is direct without going through the converter.  If you remove a class, or extend in the future, your underlying is all self-contained.

Now don't get me wrong, I do use converters and typically do with Boolean type fields to respectively show, hide, collapse controls as needed.  This is nice as I have different boolean converters such as

```
BoolToVisibleHidden = if True, make visible vs Hidden
BoolToHiddenVisible = if True, make Hidden vs Visible
BoolToVisibleCollapse = if True, make visible vs Collapsed
BoolToCollapseVisible = if True, make Collapsed vs visible.
```

So, with one boolean property on my MVVM, I can both show AND hide different controls... maybe such as an admin vs standard user option.

I've also used converters dealing with dates for alternate formatting purposes.

Comment: thanks Drapp can you explain why this works and not the prior?

Comment: @JamTay317, what do you mean "not the prior?"... Your original code vs my slightly extended version?

Comment: the previous answers with the converters.

Comment: @JamTay317, updated end of answer and also described where I have used converters.

Answer (score 0):

You could abuse `IValueConverter` for that. Create one for each column.
In the `ValueConverter` you can test for the type and return the correct property. An example of what I mean:

```
public class NameValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Students)
        {
            return (value as Students).Name;
        }
        if (value is Classes)
        {
            return (value as Classes).ClassName;
        }
        if (value is Cars)
        {
            return (value as Cars).CarType;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it add it as resource to the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:NameValueConverter x:Key="NameValueConverter"></local:NameValueConverter>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

And specify it in the binding like this:

```
{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource NameValueConverter}}
```

This solution would only work for read-only DataGrids though (editing throws a NotImplementedException).